# ngModel binding is null in OnInit in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I ran into a issue using Angular 2 ngModel binding. 
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Im5oz7q1HhG5MgGTTZ1R?p=preview)

If I use ngModel to bind a value to a child component, the value is not populated on the OnInit function of the child component. So If I bind to a property call "boundName" and I try to access that in the OnInit, it will be null. However if I bind the to the same value in the parent control not using ngModel but a input parameter, the value is accessible in the OnInit function.

So.. if my parent component creates a child component like

```
 <my-boundcomp [(ngModel)]="name" [(inputName)] ="name" ></my-boundcomp>
```

And my child components onInit Function is

```
public ngOnInit() {
   console.log("Input Name :" + this.inputName);
   console.log("Bound Name :" + this.boundName);
   this._boundNameOnInit = this.boundName; // <--- Going to be null
   this._inputNameOnInit = this.inputName; // <--- Going to be not null
```

}

I found this behavior to be odd, and unexpected.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or I am not using the FormsModule ngModel correctly, but interesting enough that I thought I should share.

Here is the full plnkr  https://plnkr.co/edit/Im5oz7q1HhG5MgGTTZ1R?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
[(ngModel)]="name"
```

sets the value of `NgModel` in `OnInit` not of `BoundValueComponent`.
When `BoundValueComponent.writeValue` is called from `NgModel`, then `boundName` is set.

I'm pretty sure this is as designed.

Comment: If that were the case, then would I access ngmodel in the oninit to get the value? that give me the same result (https://plnkr.co/edit/POWoAgw8kYJToPhJwWQw?p=preview) .

Comment: I don't think you can influence that. You can add an `@Input() ngModel;` to your component but that probably has other unwanted side effects.

Comment: I agree.. My point is, I still think there is something not quite right here. I'm not convinced this is working as designed yet, Why should you not have access to the incoming value in the OnInit.

Comment: `ngOnChanges()` is called when inputs are updated. `ngOnInit()` is called after `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time. `writeValue` is not related at all to `ngOnInit()` at all.

Comment: Right. ngOnChanges is called first.. so values are bound before the ngOnInit. So.. why when using the ngModel it appears that it has not called the writeValue. Should the ngOnChanges call populate the model and force the writeValue before the ngOnInit function is called?

Comment: `ngOnInit()` is called and the value is set just fine, but in the `NgModel` directive, not on your component because `ngModel` is not an input of your component, but an input of `NgModel`. There is just no reason at all why `writeValue` should have been called in your component. It's not related to `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124914/discussion-between-jon-z-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue. I need to get the value passed through `[(ngModel)] ` the `ngOnInit()` method. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe late here but there is a bug since angular 2. Will this be fixed when this is merged - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14988

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a "problem" if you are dependent on the value that is set via *writeValue* when using the *ControlValueAccessor*.  Since *boundName* is set and *ngOnInit* is one of the first things fired, the *writeValue* has not had a chance to run yet.

I tried adding this on some other lifecycle hooks (*AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit*) and it is still too early.  In fact if you default your *boundName* to '' or something you will notice that in *AfterViewInit* or *AfterContentInit*, it is actually nulled out before the *writeValue* is called.

For this reason, I would suggest setting your value in the *writeValue* method.  If you need it to be set only once, you can use a flag.  See your code below...

```
export class BoundValueComponent  implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

@Input() inputName: string;
boundName: string;

private _boundNameOnInit : string;
private _inputNameOnInit : string;

private initialized: boolean = false;

private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

constructor() {
}

public ngOnInit() {
   console.log("Input Name :" + this.inputName);
   console.log("Bound Name :" + this.boundName);
  // this._boundNameOnInit = this.boundName; // <--- Going to be null
   this._inputNameOnInit = this.inputName; // <--- Going to be not null
}

get value(): any {
  return this.boundName;
};

/**
* Set accessor including call the onchange callback.
*/
set value(v: any) {
  if (v !== this.boundName) {
     this.boundName = v;
     this.onChangeCallback(v);
  }
}

/**
* From ControlValueAccessor interface.
*/
writeValue(value: any) {
 this.boundName = value;

 if (!this.initialized) {
   this._boundNameOnInit = this.boundName;
   this.initialized = true;
 }
}
.......
```